# json problems on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having problems when I try to `rake db:migrate`. I get the following error:

```
Could not find json-1.7.5 in any of the sources  
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Now, I've already run `bundle install` and it gave an error when it got to json, but I try it again anyway and get the same error when it gets to json:

> Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions 
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot
> ```
>
> load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'    from
>   extconf.rb:1:in`'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/chris/.bundler/tmp/2984/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /home/chris/.bundler/tmp/2984/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

The last part says to make sure `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling, so I run this command and json installs fine:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   Successfully installed json-1.7.5
>   1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for json-1.7.5...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.7.5...

But if I try `rake db:migrate` it starts all over again with the same errors.  I've read about issues with json on Mac, but have had no luck with any of those solutions.  Any ideas?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.8, gem 1.8.15 (tried it with 1.9.1 also)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058952/why-do-i-get-an-error-installing-the-json-gem-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to install the `-dev` package. Try running this command

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

and then `bundle install` should work.

Comment: Thanks avk. This worked.  When looking for solutions I saw some threads that talked about installing DevKit, but that was for the Ruby Installer that is for Windows.  I wonder why I couldn't find your solution anywhere else... seems simple enough.  The ruby on rails guide at rubyonrails.org nor does the Agile Web Development with Rails book by Hansson mention this in setup, at least I didn't see it anywhere. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome! i had a similar issue some time back, weird but good that it has a solution :D

Comment: The only thing I should add is that I used apt-get instead of aptitude since that is what I think is default. I'm new to Linux so I don't really know much about other options.