# Rails is not creating a new app correctly - conflict with JSON 1.7.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails with a online tutorial.

```
[rails version]: Rails 3.2.13
[ruby version] : ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
```

When I execute the command:

```
rails new first_app
```

I get:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /home/philippe/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/philippe/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Sure enough, I ran `gem install json -v '1.7.7` as listed, however the results are:

```
[philippe@localhost rails_projects]$ gem install json -v '1.7.7'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing json:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /home/philippe/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/philippe/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Has anyone seen that?

Comment: Post the log from Results logged to /home/philippe/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out into a gist

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058952/why-do-i-get-an-error-installing-the-json-gem-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a "rpm" system (`Fedora` or `Red Hat`) use:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

It solved the problem for me.