# Error while trying to gem install json under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rvm

Catching this error under Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/allaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
gcc: error: generator.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.so] Ошибка 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/allaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/allaud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I am using fresh rvm and ruby 1.9.3 and have same trouble only with json gem.

The error occurs when I try to execute:

```
gem install json
```

If I add sudo everything is ok, but I cannot (and shouldn't) use sudo with rvm commands.

Comment: will this [stack over flow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058952/why-do-i-get-an-error-installing-the-json-gem-in-ubuntu) solve your problem???

Comment: What do you have in the gem_make.out ?

Comment: Sagar Bommidi, as you can see, I am using ruby 1.9.3. And there is no ruby1.9.3-dev package in my repos

Comment: philant, I have the same as I wrote in my gem_make.out

Comment: I know ruby usually hates this, but `sudo apt-get install ruby-json` seems to be working for me.

Comment: ruby-json does not help and it fetches ruby 1.8 as dependency

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

may fix it .Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Try running below commands(works for ubuntu 14.04):

`$ sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`

and then install `json`

`$ gem install json`

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-fix-this-error-when-deploying-rails-with-capistrano-using-nginx-and-puma

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked (a solution from @mjgpy3)

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-json
```